# My python flask application returns 400 Bad request

Tags: python, html, sql, flask

Basically in this application i am connecting to my sql database and trying to retrieve results for the inputs given by user which are AGE,SEX and ADMITTING DIAGNOSIS CODE.I am able to give user input for both AGE and SEX and get the required results but when i give user input for ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS_CODE it returns 400 BAD REQUEST.

My Python code:

```
import MySQLdb
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask.ext.mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)

db = MySQLdb.connect("127.0.0.1","root","","health" )

@app.route("/", methods = ['GET','POST'])
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')




@app.route("/value", methods = ['GET','POST'])
def Authenticate():
    cursor = db.cursor()
    AGE = request.form['AGE']
    SEX = request.form['SEX']
    ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS_CODE = request.form['ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS_CODE']
    #DIAGNOSIS_CODE_1= request.args['DIAGNOSIS_CODE_1']

    sql = 'select avg(LENGTH_OF_STAY),avg(TOTAL_CHARGES),(select count(*) from health where AGE = 3 and SEX = 1 and ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS_CODE = %s and DISCHARGE_STATUS = "A")/(count(*))*100 as alive,(select count(*) from health where AGE = 3 and SEX = 1 and ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS_CODE = 5849 and DISCHARGE_STATUS = "B")/(count(*))*100 as dead from health where AGE = 3 and SEX = 1 and ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS_CODE = 5849'

    entries = []
    cursor.execute(sql,(ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS_CODE))

    # Fetch all the rows in a list of lists.
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        entries.append(dict([('avg(LENGTH_OF_STAY)',row[0]),
                             ('avg(TOTAL_CHARGES)',row[1]),
                             ('dead',row[3]),
                             ('alive',row[2])

                             ]))

    return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

My HTML code:

**

```
> <form action="/value" method="post" enctype ="multipart/form-data">
> <div>Enter the Age <input type="text" name="AGE" style="border: 1px
> solid black"></div> <div>Enter the Sex <input type="text" name="SEX"
> style="border: 1px solid black"></div> <div>Enter the code <input
> type="text" name="ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS_CODE" style="border: 1px solid
> black"></div> <div><input type="submit" value=" GO"></div> </form>
```

**

Please help me out.

Comment: can you paste the urlencoded POST?  If it's not readily available, you can probably get it from something like "developer tools" in whatever browser you use.  Usually something like a "network" tab in that view.

Comment: i am not able to understand what you are asking. What is that exactly u need?

Comment: I was asking for the actual POSTed data sent to the server but I'm pretty sure it's not going to be necessary.

Comment: For these sorts of things, checking your logs for what is causing the 400 error helps immensely, btw.  There should be a stack trace somewhere on the server.
Did adding the comma help?

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
cursor.execute(sql,(ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS_CODE))
```

should be

```
cursor.execute(sql,(ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS_CODE,))
```

The difference being that (x) is equal to x while (x,) is equal to the single value tuple containing the first argument x.

Comment: Now i trying to get input for all the three as                         cursor.execute(sql,(AGE,SEX,ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS_CODE,AGE,SEX,ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS_CODE,AGE,SEX,ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS_CODE,)) but this returns None.

Comment: Okay.  This isn't really a usable piece of code though and returning None might be correct.  Additionally, given your wording, it sounds like my answer worked for you.  Since this seems to be a new question, if this answer worked for you, maybe you should make a new question specifically about the problem you're experiencing now.

Comment: I jus now found that the solution you suggested cleared the error but it does not return any results instead it returns none. Have any idea why?